# Why Android Studio doesn't fully recognize GSON Library?

Tags: android, import, dependencies, gson

Its weird because its working in the implementation, but the editor is highlighting in red the last word of the import (see attached image). And underlining the file as "with errors".

[image]

On my app gradle I have:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

on the other gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Also I have errors in the code but its running.
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to update gson dependency to 2.8.7 :
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7`'

Add `jcenter` to repositories in `build.grade (Project:%name%)`

```
      buildscript {
            repositories {
             //
                jcenter()
            }
....
          allprojects {
                repositories {
                  //
                    jcenter()
                }
            }
```

Then sync gradle. This should work.

Comment: Thanks! Just updating to 2.8.7 did the trick. I didn't need to add jcenter. Also I didnt want it because its deprecated and going down soon.

Comment: @FranGaribay Oh, i didn't know that. Probably should start migrating to mavencentra(). Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio:

- File > Project Structure > Dependencies
- + button > Library Dependency
- Search for "Gson"
- Select com.google.code.gson
- Ok, Apply
- In your java code, type Gson, then alt+enter, to get the following import:

  `import com.google.gson.Gson;`

Latest Gson at time of posting is 2.10, this method will give the latest Gson version.

Comment: Great, thanks. However, in Android Studio Electric Eel, there was no search to enter "GSON". You could just manually find it under Project Structure > Dependencies > app though after adding the `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'`.